# Hint text turning into actual text on mobile?

Tags: bug, mobile-web

You know the new hint text added to SE for the comment box? On WP8 it's turning into actual text you have to delete before you can wrote your comment. I can't show a screenshot, on my phone. It seems to work fine on Desktop though.

Any ideas?

Comment: As an aside: this is (also) commonly referred to [as "placeholder text"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder).